# Trying to find what proof works best with this question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, solution-verification

If  $ (n+1)^2   $ is even then   $ n $    is odd

The work part isn't the issue for me it's finding what is the best and most simple proof to use on this question

My three options are Direct proof, Indirect proof(Contrapositive) or proof by Contradiction

I know n is odd if $N=2k+1$
N is even if $n=2k$

I want to say solving it by Contrapositive is the best method because you flip n to Even which will make it easier

Comment: Always go direct if possible

Comment: I disagree.  This is a perfect set up for contrapositive.  If $n$ is even then $n+1$ is odd and $(n+1)^2$ is odd.  So by contrapositive we are done.  To do it directly we must prove that if $(n+1)^2 = 2k$ then somehow that means $n+1$ is even and that mean $n$ is odd.  A little harder.

Comment: @fleablood, I take it you mean that you disagree with bounceback, and I would then agree with you and the OP.

Comment: Yes, I was disagreeing with bounceback.  It's not a lot harder.  But it's a bit of work.  And anyway, a direct proof that $M^2$ even $\implies M$ even that is *not* a proof by contrapositive is significantly more work.  If easy to show directly that $M$ odd $\implies M^2$ odd but not so easy to show *directly* that $M^2$ even $\implies M$ even.

Comment: "I know n is odd if N=2k+1 N is even if n=2k"  A nitpick.  It is more accurate and correct so say that if $n$ is odd then you know that $n=2k+1$ *for some integer $k$*.  And that if $n$ is even then $n=2k$ *for some integer $k$*.   Also you should be aware that you are assume that one or the other must be true and never both and never neither.  (How do you know there isn't some integer that can be $n = 2k$ *and* $n=2m+1$ for some integers $k,m$.  And how do you know there isn't some integer $n\ne 2k$ and $n\ne 2m+1$ for *any* integers $k,m$.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this by proving the contrapostive, as you suggest.  The contrapostive of the statement, which is equivalent to the statement, is:

> If $n$ is even, then $(n+1)^2$ is odd.

Assume $n$ is even.  So $n= 2k$, for some integer $k$.  Then $(n+1)^2 = n^2+ 2n + 1 =  (2k)^2 + 2(2k) + 1 =  4k^2 + 4k + 1= 2(2k^2+ 2k) +1 = 2m+1$,  which is an odd integer, (noting that we can represent $m = 2k^2+2k$, another integer, given that $k$ is an integer.)

Answer (score 0):

If $(n+1)^2$ is even, then $n+1$ is even, and so $n$ is odd. Don't overthink it.

Comment: How do you know if $(n+1)^2$ is even then $n+1$ is even?

Comment: odd times odd is odd, even times even is even

Comment: But how can you prove *directly* (NOT contrapositive) that square root of even is even?

Comment: I don't have to. It's a common misconception coming out of Intro to Proofs that ones options are 'direct, contradiction, induction'. Students over-rely on the latter two, with many producing false 'proofs' by contradiction. Realistically, the statement of the problem usually makes clear what method of proof to go for, and if in doubt the first thought should be to go direct.

Comment: And yet you made the statement "Always go direct if possible" emphasizing the trichotomy that proofs be an absolute one type over another.  That's what I object to. It doesn't matter what type of proof you do if you have a good argument.  In this case numbers are either even or odd and if $n$ is even or odd we can evaluate what $(n+1)^2$ is or result falls from that.  but that is *not* a "direct proof". Eliminating $n\ even \implies (n+1)^2\ odd$ so $(n+1)^2\ even \implies n+1\ even\implies n\ odd$ is contrapositive reasoning. we shouldn't all hail direct when we are being contrapositive.

Answer (score -1):

I'm reading this 2 years later and ... I don't really like it.  I'd like a redo:

Direct proof: Requires $(n+1)^2\implies .... \implies n$ is odd.  Our obvious second step and second to last steps are:  $(n+1)^2\implies (n+1)^2 = 2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z\implies ..... \implies n+1$ is even so $n=(n+1)-1$ is odd.

The missing step is that $\frac {(n+1)^2}2 = k\implies n+1$ is even but why? Well, we'd need Euclid's lemma. As $2$ is prime then $2|(n+1)^2 \implies 2|n+1$ so $n+1$ is even.

That's it.  It's not hard but it does require more thought and explanation than required.

Contrapositive:  Requires proving $n$ not odd $\implies.... \implies (n+1)^2$ is not even.

The obvious second and second to last steps are: $n$ not odd $\implies n$ is even $\implies .... \implies (n+1)^2$ is odd $\implies (n+1)^2$ is not even.

And we need to fill in the blanks.  I don't know about you but it strikes me the obvious relating of $n$ to $(n+1)^2$ is to go from $n$ to $n+1$ to $(n+1)^2$ and it is obvious what to do

$n$ not odd $\implies$
$n$ is even $\implies$
$n+1$ is odd $\implies$
$(n+1)^2$ is odd $\implies$
$(n+1)^2$ is not even.

That seems the most straight forward and simple way.

Proof by contradiction:  Requires assuming $(n+1)^2$ is even and $n$ is even leads to a contradiction.

Not hard.  $n$ is even means $n+1$ is odd and $(n+1)^2$ is odd contradiction $(n+1)^2$ is even.

But we never actually *used* $(n+1)^2$ is even except as a contrast to $(n+1)^2$ is odd.  This is essentially the contrapositive proof but with as assuming $(n+1)^2$ is even for no real purpose.

Given that... I'd say the contrapositive route is the most natural.

(Actually, I'd just do it and not even think about it....

(Okay, how do I "just do it"?... Well, these are basically toggled either it is odd/ or it is even and as such it falls naturally to me that this is more or less establishing a truth table.  As "parity of $k$ implies parity of $f(k)$" is far more direct and easy to establish than "parity of $f(k)$ implies parity of $x$" I'd say that if we were to do a proof of "parity of $f(k)$ implies parity of $x$ proof, I'd choose the contrapositive of "opposite party of $x$ implies opposite party of $f(x)$" as being far more simple and direct.)

=== old answer below =====

Direct requires proving that if $(n+1)^2$ is even then $n+1$ is even.  And the only real way I see to do that is be contrapositive.  If $n+1=2k$ is even then $(n+1)^2 = 4k^2$ is even but if $(n+1) =2k + 1$ is odd then $(n+1)^2=4k^2 + 4k + 1= 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1$ is odd.  Or by claiming by Euclid's Lemma that $2$ is prime so if $2|(n+1)^2$ then $2|n+1$ and $n+1$ is even.  Then once we know $n+1$ is even then $n+1 = 2k$ so $n = 2k-1$ is odd.

That's not hard but it's more work.

COntrapositive is fairly.... er, dirct.....  If $n=2k$ is even then $n+1 = 2k+1$ is odd, and $(n+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k + 1$ is odd.  So contrapositively if $(n+1)^2$ is *not* odd then $n$ is *not* even.  Done.

Proof by contradiction sets up unnecessary conditions:

Suppose $(n+1)^2$ even and $n$ is even.  Then $n+1$ is odd and $(n+1)^2$ is odd so that's a contradcition.

Fine, but why did we need to suppose $(n+1)^2$ was even.

I'd go with contrapositive.

But they are all relatively easy and straightforward.

Comment: Seems reasonable. why down-vote?

Comment: Hmmm... rereading this 2 years later I think I'm not being clear on "direct" vs. "contrapositive" and call a contrapostive proof "direct" and the whole thing is muddled.  I'm not sure I wouldn't have downvoted.